# How can I distinct or count all same emails in database that have a status = false?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to count all same emails who's `status:false` in my mongodb database?, so for example here I have a 5 object, and `sample_1@gmail.com` and `sample_1@gmail.com`. So the total count of email should be `2`.

```
[
   {
     'email':"sample_1@gmail.com",
     'affiliation':"njmpti_students",
     'category': 'students',
     'status': false

   },

   {
     'email':"sample_1@gmail.com",
     'affiliation':"njmpti_students",
     'category': 'students',
     'status': false
   },
   {
     'email':"sample_2@gmail.com",
     'affiliation':"njmpti_students",
     'category': 'students',
     'status': true
   },
   {
     'email':"sample_2@gmail.com",
     'affiliation':"njmpti_students",
     'category': 'students',
     'status': true
   },
   {
     'email':"sample_3@gmail.com",
     'affiliation':"njmpti_students",
     'category': 'students',
     'status': false
   },
]
```

This is what I did, but now I get stucked on this part.

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'status': False
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'category': 'students'
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'affiliation': 'njmpti_students'
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $group aggregation operator by email to resolve this. Here is the solution:

```
db.sample.aggregate([
  {
     $match: {
       status: false
     }
  },
  {
   $group: {
     _id: '$email',
     count: {
       $sum: 1
     }
   }
}]);
```

I have pasted image as well for your reference as well.

[image]

Comment: The query looks good the only problem is of projection because _id is not a suitable field name for projection email so @Stykgwar try using this one -
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: false
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$email",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0, // Exclude _id field
      email: "$_id",
      count: 1
    }
  }
]);